# Agregar otro cero al resultado

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código y necesito que por ejemplo, si en el **primer campo ingreso 10** y en el **segundo 20**, me muestra:

> 0.5 USD

pero necesito que muestre

> 0.50 USD

```
<form oninput="x.value=parseFloat(peso.value)/parseFloat(dolar.value)">

        <input type="number" id="peso" placeholder="pesos" value="">
        <br>
        <input type="number" id="dolar" placeholder="dolares" value="">
        <hr>

        <output name="x"></output> USD

</form>
```

Comment: se tan amable de agregar el código que haz tratado hasta el momento

Comment: si lo agregue, pero no se  por que no se mostró, pero agregue una captura.

Comment: agregalo y luego seleccionalo y dale click al ícono {} para que le de formato y se muestre y de preferencia elimina la imagen

Comment: listo, gracias Alferdo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que justo te acaba de responder correctamente BDOM, pero de todas formas te pongo tu ejemplo que acabo de probar para que funcione como has indicado, como te ha dicho BDOM tienes que usar el metodo toFixed()

```html
<form oninput="x.value=(parseFloat(peso.value,2)/parseFloat(dolar.value)).toFixed(2)">

        <input type="number" id="peso" placeholder="pesos" value="">
        <br>
        <input type="number" id="dolar" placeholder="dolares" value="">
        <hr>

        <output name="x"></output> USD

</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no encontraba como aplicarlo xD

Answer (score 3):

Utiliza `Number.prototype.toFixed`. Con esto le indicas que quieres 2 decimales después del punto. Por ejemplo:

```
var a = 15.3;
alert(a.toFixed(2));
```

Espero te ayude.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda! :)

Comment: Por nada, que bueno que te sirviera, y disculpas por no aplicar todo el código, menos mal que un compañero ya lo agregó. Saludos.